# Proxmox server issues

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, proxmox

Okay, so i have never really dealt with live servers and data centers in a practical situation. I guess my knowledge in this area is pretty much 0 as i have only ever worked behind a home/office AP, using 1 public IP, and only a few devices on a particular network. My web hosting/development experience has all been from a hosted cPanel, and some experience hosting with apache2, i am familiar with port forwarding, and have learned a lot in general over the last few months using some of the later Linux distros. Anyway.

Networking, or dealing with subnets just isn't my strong point right now. I have been studying virtualization, and i am familiar with the use of virtualbox and VMWare player for desktop use, however, not having much problems in the past with defaults or given configurations it's not been such an issue... It may seem like i am just incompetent and i suppose i am in some areas which is why i'd really like for all to share any information in regards to learning material...

This is my situation... I have been given access to a ***dedicated server***, it is ***in a data center***, and has been ***allocated 13 IPv4 addresses***, the server Host is running Proxmox VE 4.3, at this stage the D/L is rather slow, but working.. However, we need to create VM's in Proxmox, and assign the IP's from the block given to make them able to be addressed individually from the web.

As i said, it may seem stupid as hell to some of you, this just is not something i've had practical experience with yet. I don't expect anyone to spend to much time on this, just some guidance would be really appreciated.

http://help.ovh.com/Proxmox <<<< = This is the page i am currently looking at, however i know for fact that OVH has some differences in default configs so that also has added to the confusion a little. Do i need to be able to associate MAC addresses with IP's for what i am trying to do?

***UPDATED AND MOVED.  Now after installing from an ISO on a VM, removing the ISO, and trying to boot, it will not even start, it hangs and says "started update UTMP about system runlevel changes.."
This is so much more trouble than i had running virtualization on an internal network.***

We also have access to a working VM that is on a remote proxmox server, but not the host server itself.

Kindest regards,

Comment: Which OVH server did you get? And how are your IPv4 addresses routed?

Comment: I am sorry if it is was clear, i am using a dedicated server from another company, but they referred me to this OVH page mentioned in the question, and right now, only host has default network configurations using the info provided. The remaining IP's afaik aren't configured in any way.. I've never had more than one Public IP to deal with so this has me really confused.  And to add to the confusion, my VM will not even boot after install.

Comment: I chose to try install and configure the network later on but seems i am not even at a point where i can do that.  :( Networking and managing a remote server on this level is something i need to find clear information about or someone willing to teach me what i'm missing here.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two important points before tackling your issue

1. the block of IP were you used for VPSs, are they different from
   the IP address of the host server itself?
2. Did you created virtual
   MAC address with your IPs? this is a must in OVH, then you need to
   assign the MAC address associated with the IP address to the machine
   you assinged that IP address.

tThen will come to the main point which is some sort of routing and NATING. for example, if you host IP address is as bellow:

```
IP address 1.1.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 1.1.1.1
```

and ypu have this pool of IP addresses to be assigned to your VPSs (200.1.1.20-200.1.1.40)

so the first VPS will be like this:

```
ip address 200.1.1.20
netasmk 255.255.255.255
broadcast 200.1.1.20
dns-nameservers 8.8.8
post-up route add 1.1.1.1 dev eth0    (this is the interface of your VPS)
post-up route add default gw 1.1.1.1
post-down route del 1.1.1.1 dev eth0
post-down route del default gw 1.1.1.1
```